# some questions about DOM based XSS

Tags: javascript, xss, web-browser

1. Is it possible to do a DOM based xss attack with window.location.protocol?
2. How can we use dom based xss with document.title?
3. How can we bypass the escape javascript function if it is used?

thank you

Comment: 1: no  2: not possible 3:  what escape function?

Comment: Hi there. If you could clarify your questions, and separate them out, these may be more suitable, however I think you can see from the comment and answer what you will get.

Answer (score 2):

1. No
2. I'm not sure what you mean? You can't "break out" of `document.title=AttackerString` where *AttackerString* is a javascript variable with data (the string value) controlled by you.
3. Again, you can't exploit `escape(AttackerString)` but you can exploit something like `<? echo 'escape("' .$_GET['AttackerString']. '");' ?>` by simply bypass the javascript function: `&AttackerString="); alert("xss` in the case the html output would be: `escape(""); alert("xss");`